# Google tag manager variable based on class name and pushed at history change

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I have a single page application I need to set up a variable for in Google tag manager. I'm using history change for page view triggers.

So the datalayer need to be pushed on load and on each history change event.
the Variable should list out all the innerText of div class x separated by comma.

Is this possible? The below is only getting first div class x innertext on window load.

Html

```
<div class="x"> tag 1</div>
<div class="x"> tag 2</div>
<div class="x"> tag 3</div>
<div class="x"> tag 4</div>
```

Google tag manager variable

```
function() {
 return window.document.getElementsByClassName('x')[0].innerText; 
}
```

Variable output:
tag 1, tag 2, tag 3, tag 4

I want add the variable as a custom dimension for page views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a Custom JavaScript variable. Something like this should do the trick:

```
function(){
  // Empty array that will store your comma separated list
  var myVariable = [];

  // Create array of all elements with class "x"
  var myArray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.x'));

  // Loop through myArray to get text and push to comma separated list
  myArray.forEach(function(element){
    myVariable.push(element.innerHTML);
  })

  // Return comma separated list
  return myVariable;
}
```

You can then you can use this variable as the value of your custom dimension.